# SOAPUI Groovy - How do I access a Property added to MessageExchange, using testStepResult object?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is it possible to add a property to messageExchange object in an "Assertion Script", and retrieve the value of this property later in "TestSuite TearDown Script"?

Basically, I want to get how many records REST API retrieved, in "TestSuite TearDown Script" window. I want to do this, without needing to process the responses of all steps in the "TestSuite TearDown Script".

This is how I am adding a property in "Assertion Script"

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
def resp = messageExchange.response.responseContent;
def jslurp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(resp);
messageExchange.addProperty("recordCount",Integer.toString(jslurp.size()));
```

I want to retrieve "recordCount" in "TestSuite TearDown Script", for all the 40+ REST API results that are executed as part of my TestSuite.

Somehow, if I am able to obtain a reference to the messageExchange object of each step from testStepResult, I should be able to achieve what I am trying to do.

Any pointers or your thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've never had to retrieve a property from an object set in one part of soapUI and used in another. I have a feeling soapUI doesn't share that way.

So, what about setting a custom property at, say the test-suite level? In your assertion script, you can use `messageExchange` to set a property like this:

```
def recordCounter = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.
    setPropertyValue('recordCounter', 'your number');
```

Then, in your tear-down script you could retrieve it with:

```
def recordCounter = context.expand('${#TestSuite#recordCounter}')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, I execute a few steps multiple times, so writing recordCount of each execution to testCase/testSuite properties would make it cumbersome. That's why I was hoping to add properties Assertion Script's messageExchange and access them from testStepResult (more specifically RestRequestStepResult) object.

Comment: Cumbersome in what way? Updating the property is just a single statement. You could even put it into an [event handler](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/custom-event-handlers.html) rather than an assertion and have it fired automatically.